# Why do tengo/tienes use different words?

Tags: gramática

I understand the grammar of 'yo como' and 'tú comes'. That's vey regular.

But 'yo tengo' and 'tú tienes' don't seem to be related to each other.  Why does the prefix change instead of just the suffix?

Comment: The verb tener has an irregular conjugation, that's why.

Comment: let's say that tener is an old verb that comes from latin, very used every year. This means, more use by the people means more changes along the years, coming as an irregular verb.